# How to find out that connecting disconnected midiDevice failed in C++/WinRT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy, midi, reaper

I'm creating a plugin for the REAPER DAW to support a BLE MIDI input. Code is as follows:

```
fire_and_forget MidiDeviceService::connectDevice(hstring deviceId, bool updateConfig = true)
{
    if (!deviceId.empty())
    {
        currentDevice = co_await MidiInPort::FromIdAsync(deviceId);
        if (!currentDevice) {}
        {
            ShowMessageBox("Couldn't connect to device.", "Connection Error", 0);
            co_return;
        }
        messageReceivedEventToken = currentDevice.MessageReceived({this, &MidiDeviceService::midiInPort_messageReceived});
    }
    if (updateConfig)
    {
        configuredDeviceId = deviceId;
        setCurrentDeviceInConfig(configuredDeviceId);
    }
}
```

This works like a charm when trying to connect to a MIDI device that's connected to the system. However, when trying to connect to a BLE MIDI device that is out of range, as soon as I co_await co_await MidiInPort::FromIdAsync, the calling thread freezes for five seconds and then the rest of the fire_and_forget is simply not executed.

I tried several things, including changing the fire_and_forget to an IAsyncAction and get the result from that in the synchronous code that executes this, but all with the same result. If I step through the coroutine with the Visual Studio debugger, after the co_await freezes the caller for five seconds, the cursor instantly jumps to the bottom of the coroutine.

I might be doing something horribly wrong, but there's no information in the Docs as of what the behavior should be when the connection to a device fails (e.g. should it just return nullptr, should it throw an exception)?